# Eclipse Juno OSx Tabs too large

Tags: eclipse, macos, tabs, styles

The new style tabs on eclipse Juno are just too big (specially on height) on MacOSx!! Insane waste of space!

Any ideas on having them smaller?

Comment: which version of juno sr1 or sr2 ? Did you try to update your eclipse ?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: When on the version:
Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800 tabs were fine

Comment: i refuse to upgrade from 3.8.2 solely for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe it is a bug with the theme. Try changing the theme to the old one : window > preferences > General > Appearance > Theme

Comment: Thanks Willome, I did that but it was not effective. Still got very big tabs, wasting screen space.